# css3 transitions, not working width transition of right navigation column

Tags: css, width, transition

What could be the reason of the not working width transition of right navigation column.

If i make simple demo - it works ( on hover column width increases), but in a full project - width is not changing, though column is moving to the left.

I am sorry i have removed the links to demonstration with error and demo, because i have found one if the reasons and described in the solution with the code example to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the error

1) with the small mistake in the syntax,  missing `;`, or `,` instead of `;` in transition definition.

2) by putting !important on width on the element, but not on the transition.

If you make a mistake in several transition listing - the transitions until the mistake (`left`) will occur until the mistake ( the right nav bar width increase by given amount ). The rest of transitions will not be working (`width`) ( the right nav bar will be moving to the left, but preserving its width ).

```
//ERROR
@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
    div.navWrapT:hover { 
        left:30vw; width:70vw, right:1px;  //will give this error
    } 
}

//CORRECT

@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
    div.navWrapT:hover { 
        left:30vw; width:70vw !important; right:1px; 
    } 
}
```

Full code ( you can remove right totally, to get it working ):

```
<style>

div.sliderWrap { 
    height: 100vh;
    width: 90vw;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px; 
    overflow : hidden;
    z-index : 100;
}

.nav { width : 70vw; }

div.navWrapT {
    position :absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 70vw;
    width : 28vw;
    right: 1px; 
    border:  0px;  /*3px solid violet;  //remove the border to make it working  */
    margin : 5px; 
    padding : 0px;
    height : 100%;
    background : green; 
    transition: width ease-out 1s, left ease-out 1s, right ease-out 1s;
        /*   */
}

a.aBtn {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative; 
  /*  transition: 0.5s all;    */
  /* transition-delay: 1s; */
  height: 30px;
  width : 100%; 
  /* transition: width ease-out 1s, left ease-out 1s; */
}

span.navDescr {
    color : back;
} 


@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
    div.navWrapT:hover { 
        left:30vw; width:70vw, right:1px;  
        /* */
    } 
}
 </style>




  <div class="outestWrap" >
  <div class="sliderWrap" >
  <span class="nav">
 <span class="nav">

 <div class="navWrapT" >

<a href="#nav0_1" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Main</span></a>

<a href="#nav0_2" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Location, map</span></a>

<a href="#nav0_3" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Room types, suites </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_4" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Busines, office, work room </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_5" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Parking </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_6" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Services </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_7" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Policies </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_8" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Food/cloth/hygiene </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_9" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Transport </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_10" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Sport </span></a>

<a href="#nav0_11" class="aBtn"><span class="navDescr">Awards, history, about </span></a>

</div>

      <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>

 </span></span>
      </div> </div>
```